# Determining if (infinite) binary language DFAs contain at least 1 prime?

Tags: regular-languages, automata, discrete-mathematics, number-theory

This problem has been given by [Shallit](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/3227/jeffrey-shallit) as an open DFA/ complexity theory problem and is currently not even known to be decidable. It seems to be circulating on the internet in a few places (e.g. [1][2]) but not in any papers. Almost nothing seems to be known or published. I am looking for any nontrivial analysis or references.

> Given: binary DFA D. Does L(D) contain at least 1 prime?

(Binary means Σ = {0, 1}.) As an example of something nontrivial about it (a subproblem), what can be said of the base-2 DFA language representations, what is their general form? Or, given any *d,* does there exist a DFA (language) that contains only multiples of *d* in binary? Are there arithmetic progressions embedded in DFA binary languages? Note there are many number theoretic investigations into [primes in arithmetic sequences/ progressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primes_in_arithmetic_progression) and [recent findings/ research](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Green%e2%80%93Tao_theorem), could any be demonstrated to be applicable?

[1] [a simple problem whose decidability is not known](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/18846/a-simple-problem-whose-decidability-is-not-known/32701#32701) / cstheory.SE

[2] [are there any open problems left about DFAs?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/22493/are-there-any-open-problems-left-about-dfas/22503#22503) / cstheory.SE

Comment: Just a note: the problem is decidable over unary alphabets ($\Sigma = \{1\}$). Indeed, in that case, the regular language forms a semilinear set; so for each one of the arithmetic progressions $\{a + ib \mid i  > 0\}$ of the semilinear set (that can be computed efficiently), if $a,b$ are coprimes, then by Dirichlet's theorem, the sequence contains infinite primes.

Comment: fyi/ thx [MW](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/14207/michael-wehar) for this ref in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9446/theory-salon): [Minimal Elements for the Prime Numbers](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/~shallit/Papers/br10.pdf)/ Bright, Devillers, Shallit

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a standard intro theory [exercise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deterministic_finite_automaton) that for any $d\ge 0$ there's a FA that accepts all and only those strings in $\{0, 1\}^*$ that are the binary representations of integer multiples of $d$. Thus, the answer to your second question is "yes".

For your third question, the answer is "no". Consider the regular language denoted by $1(10)^*0$. This language consists of those binary representations of
$$
\frac{10\cdot 4^n-4}{3}
$$
and clearly this sequence is too sparse to contain an arithmetic subsequence of any length greater than 2.

Comment: To hint at how to construct such a DFA for a given $d$: make the initial state the only final state, and count modulo $d$.